# Ruby on Rails executing database query

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to execute some particular query on the button click in Ruby on Rails. I have created a table histories. In the beginning it is showing all the data. Here is my haml page

```
%h1 History

%br
%br

%table#views
  %tbody
    %tr
      %td
      %td
        %input{:required => "", :type => "text"}
      %td
        %input{:required => "", :type => "submit", :value => "Search"}


%table#houses
  %thead
    %tr
      %th UserName
      %th User ID
      %th Email
      %th Rented House
      %th Start Date
      %th End Date
      %th Total Cost ($)
      %th Rating
  %tbody
    - @histories.each do |history|
      %tr
        %td= history.user_name
        %td= history.user_id
        %td= history.email
        %td= history.house_address
        %td= history.start_date
        %td= history.end_date
        %td= history.total_cost
        %td= history.rating

= link_to 'Back to Welcome page', users_path
```

Now there is a text box. I want to do it in such a way that when I click search it will execute the query and show data whose username is entered in the box.

Can somebody help me on this?

Thank you and Regards

Comment: I assume you're going to search in your welcome page?

Comment: I have a history page where I want to search it

Answer (score 0):

you can do a simple search to return that data. 
something like this

(model) history.rb

```
def self.search(search)
  where("title LIKE ?", "%#{search}%")
end
```

*this is using SQLLite

(controller)history_controller.rb

```
  def index
    @histories = Histories.all
    if params[:search]
      @histories = Histories.search(params[:search]).order("created_at DESC")
    else
      @histories = Histories.all.order('created_at DESC')
    end
  end
```

(haml/view)

```
 = form_tag(history_path, :method => "get", id: "search-form") do
  = text_field_tag :search, params[:search], placeholder: "Search Username", :class => "form-control"
```

Comment: Its showing the text box and in it's written Search Username but nothing is happening... like I want to show the records whose username will match in  the textbox.

Comment: maybe that video will help you out more?

Comment: It's done thank you just one more thing... in the query its "LIKE" but I want a query which is user_name = ....What will that query be in there?